# JQuery POST to Handler Data Params

Tags: jquery, httphandler

Onlu just started picking up JQuery and came across a problem.  Im trying to post to a Generic Handler and pass it Data Params.

The function looks like this:-

```
 function callSwapClaimHandler() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/handlers/investor-tickets/claimswapvalidator.ashx",
            data: { investorId : '1', investorTicketId : '2', originalClaimId : '3', newClaimId : '4' },
            contentType: "text/html charset=uft-8",
            success:
                function (data) {
                $("[id$='divMessageData']").html(data);
            }

        });
```

When i debug the function being called, it posts to the handler, and i can step through my code.

The problem is that Request form keys are empty, i have none of the above parameters.

Am i looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling `$.ajax` to send the request data as `"text/html"` by using the `contentType` option.

You likely meant to set the `dataType` which refers to the response.

Simply removing the `contentType` property should remedy problem.

**From [$.ajax Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

> **contentType** (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
>   When sending data to the server, use this content type.
>
> **dataType** (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>   Type: String The type of data that you're expecting back from the
>   server.